# Obtener fecha del sistema

Tags: c++, date, localtime

Estoy haciendo un programa en #C para la universidad y necesito obtener la fecha actual del sistema para saber en que momento se ha registrado la persona.

Hasta ahora para coger la fecha tengo esto:

```
time_t tiempo = time(NULL);//variables donde guardo el valor de la funcion time. 
    struct tm *tlocal = localtime(&tiempo); //estructura donde obtengo el tiempo 
    char output[10]; //array donde guardo la fecha
    strftime(output,10,"%d/%m/%y",tlocal); //formato para guardar la fecha obtenido en *tlocal como dd/mm/yyyy
    printf("%s\n",output);
```

El problema lo tengo en que haciendo esto la fecha se me guarda correctamente pero el año solo tiene 2 dígitos, es decir, en vez de guardar 10/04/2017 guarda 10/04/17.

He buscado por internet como guardar la fecha completa con todos los dígitos y he leido que si en la función `strftime` pongo la `y` en mayúsculas me guarda los 4 dígitos del año pero lo he probado y no me funciona.

¿Alguna idea para obtener la fecha del sistema en formato dd/mm/yyyy?.

Comment: Este codigo no es c#,mas bien c++ no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char output[10];
strftime(output,10,"%d/%m/%y",tlocal);
```

Una fecha en formato dd/mm/YYYY ocupa:

- 2 dígitos (día)
- 2 dígitos (mes)
- 4 dígitos (año)
- 2 dígitos (separadores)
- 1 dígito (fin de cadena)

En total 11 caracteres... y tu arreglo es de únicamente 10.

Lo que está sucediendo es que `strftime` detecta que no le va a entrar el año y lo omite para no escribir en zonas de memoria que no le pertenecen a tu arreglo.

La solucion es tan sencilla como cambiar el tamaño del buffer para que admita un mínimo de 11 caracteres):

```
char output[11];
strftime(output,11,"%d/%m/%Y",tlocal);
```

Comment: Tenias razón. No me cogía bien la fecha porque no cabía en el array de caracteres al ser mas pequeño. La solución sin duda ha sido aumentar al array a 11 caracteres en vez de a 10. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar la cabecera [`<chrono>`](http://sn.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) de C++11 para obtener el momento actual e imprimirlo por consola así:

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);

std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&time), "%d-%m-%Y");
```

Este código requiere la cabecera [`<chrono>`](http://sn.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) para acceder a las utilidades de tiempo y la cabecera [`<iomanip>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) para transformar los valores de tiempo en texto (además de [`<iostream>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream) para escribir en la consola, pero eso ya dependerá de tus necesidades).

Answer (score 1):

Las librerías std C nos aportan la función `time()`. También se puede formatear en Horas:Minutos:Segundos utilizando las funciones de C.

```
time_t  timev;
time(&timev);
```

Comment: Deberías considerar el ampliar tu respuesta añadiendo un ejempo un poco más completo. ¿Cómo genera el texto con la fecha a partir de lo devuelto por la función `time()`? ¿Vas a hacer que lo investigue el usuario? ¿Y qué sucede con todos los que pasen después con una duda similar?