# ¿Cómo contar cuantas veces se ejecuta el ciclo for?

Tags: c

en el problema me pide solicitar el año en que nació
si nació antes del 2000 poner la frase "Eres analogico" y contar de cero a su edad
y si nació en el 2000 o más poner la frase "Eeres digital" y un conteo de su edad al año que nació
sólo se que es con if-else y ciclos de for a parte de usar únicamente la libreria stdio.h 
aqui les dejo mi codigo

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  main ()
{
int n;
printf("Dame tu anio de nacimiento:\n");
scanf("%d",& n);
if (n<=1999)
{
printf ("Eres analogico");
}
else 
{
    printf("Eres digital");
}
return (0);
}
```

Comment: Donde tienes intención de poner el bucle for? Para que lo necesitas? Leyendo tu pregunta con el if-else ya debería hacer lo que deseas.

Comment: No entiendo "conteo de su edad al año en que nació". ¿Qué debe hacer el bucle? ¿Calcular su edad? (para eso no hace falta bucle, basta restar el año actual menos el de nacimiento) ¿Imprimir algo tantas veces como edad tenga? ¿Imprimir quizás una cuenta atrás desde el año actual hasta el año en que nació? Aclara mejor esto, por favor

Comment: yo ahi entiendo, por ej: si nacio en el 1970, (estando en el 2018) tiene 48 años. Pues tiene que presentar un conteo desde `48,49,50... 1968,1969,1970`

Answer (score 1):

Dentro del else puedes inicializar tu contador y poner un for de manera que te haga el conteo ahí dentro.

```
else{
{
     int cont = 0;
     for (int i=2000;i<n+1;i++){
            cont++;
     }
     cout<<"Eres digital"<<cont;
}
```

Comment: Perdón, estaba pensando en otro lenguaje. Ahora si que estaría bien el for

Comment: Efectivamente el `for()` va del año 2000 al año de nacimiento, pero el transcurso del tiempo se cuenta con un contador `cont` a parte para ir contando los años

Comment: Qué es OP? No he indicado lo de ser  posterior al año 2000 porque lo he dado por hecho ya al estar en el èlse` la condición, siento si no ha quedad claro

Comment: OP hace referencia al usuario que hizo la pregunta, es un acrónimo de *Original Poster*

Answer (score 1):

Yo la solucion que veo aqui es la siguiente:

voy a usar dos variables, una `inicio_contador` y otra `fin_contador`.
primero pedir el año (como has hecho):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main ()
{
    int n, inicio_contador, fin_contador;
    printf("Dame tu anio de nacimiento:\n");
    scanf("%d",& n);
```

En caso de ser <=1999, imprime analogico y configura las variables anteriores como inicio_contador igual a 0, y fin_contador como edad. En caso else, el inicio contador es igual a 0, y fin_contador es

```
if (n<=1999) {
    printf ("Eres analogico");
    inicio_contador = 0;
    fin_contador = 2018 - n;
}
else {
    printf("Eres digital");
    inicio_contador = 2018 - n;
    fin_contador = n;
}
```

Por ultimo, vamos a recorrer un for. Este se hace desde el inicio_contador (ya seteado con el valor correspondiente) hasta el fin_contador.

```
for(int cont = inicio_contador; cont <=fin_contador; cont++) {
    printf("%d\n", cont);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para determinar cuantas veces se ejecuta el ciclo `for`, puedes usar la misma variable que será incrementada:

```
int numero_ciclos = 12;
//for inicia en 0 
//terminara cuando i sea igual  o menor a "numero_ciclos"
for (int i = 0 ; i <= numero_ciclos ; i ++){
    printf("contando %d\n", j);           
}
```

salida:

```
contando 0
contando 1
contando 2
contando 3
contando 4
contando 5
contando 6
contando 7
contando 8
contando 9
contando 10
contando 11
contando 12
```

Si lo que quieres es determinar la edad en base a el año en que naciste puedes agregar un contador de años que se incremente en cada bucle y determine la edad, ejemplo:

```
int anio_nacimiento = 1985;
int anio_actual = 2018;    
int contador_anios = 0;
//for inicia en año de nacimiento 
//terminara cuando año de nacimiento  sea igual  o menor a año actual.-
for (int i = anio_nacimiento ; i < anio_actual ; i++){
    //printf("contando %d\n", i);           
    //contador de años se incrementa en cada bucle.
    contador_anios++;
}    
printf("Tu edad es: %d\n", contador_anios);
```

Salida:

```
Tu edad es: 33 años!
```

---

Por lo tanto de acuerdo a lo anterior puedes realizar los siguiente para determinar la edad y además determinar si la persona es "analógica" o "digital" :

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() {

    int n;
    int anio_actual = 2018;
    printf("Dame tu anio de nacimiento:\n");
    scanf("%d", & n);    

    //Variable para conteo de años.
    int i;
    //Variable para determinar años.
    int anios = 0; 
    for (i = n;i<anio_actual;i++){
        printf("contando %d\n", i);
        anios++;        
    }    
    printf("Tienes : %d años\n", anios);        

    if (n <= 1999) {
        printf("Eres analógico");
    } else {
        printf("Eres digital");
    }

    return (0);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Primero podriamos comprobar el año introducido mediante un if y un else aunque seria mas eficiente hacerlo de la siguiente manera(defino una variable i, para poder usarla en los bucles for):

```
    int i;
    if(edad>=2000){
      printf("Eres digital");
      for(i=edad;i<=anio;i++)
         printf("%d",i);
      }
     else{
        printf("Eres analogico");   
        for(i=0;i<=edad;i++)
            printf("%d",i);
        }
```

Esa seria la estructura de un if, un else y dos fors, con tal de comprobar si ha nacido en el 2000 o mas adelante, y por tanto muestra por pantalla el mensaje "Eres digital" y una serie de numeros, desde su edad, hasta el año en el que nacio. Si nacio antes del 2000, muestra por pantalla el mensaje "Eres analogico" y una serie de numeros desde el 0 hasta la edad introducida por el usuario.

Answer (score -1):

No recuerdo exactamente como se realiza en en c++

Pero espero se entienda la lógica:

Con esto tendrías que obtener el año actual, así no tendrás que estar modificando el año --> [referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62201/obtener-fecha-del-sistema) :

```
//Obtener el año   
 time_t tiempo = time(NULL);//variables donde guardo el valor de la funcion time. 
        struct tm *tlocal = localtime(&tiempo); //estructura donde obtengo el tiempo 
        char output[5]; //array donde guardo la fecha
        strftime(output,5,"%y",tlocal); //formato para guardar la fecha obtenido en *tlocal como yyyy
        //printf("%s\n",output);
```

Luego aquí calcularías su edad y a que era pertenece sin usar "for"

```
int n;
printf("Dame tu anio de nacimiento:\n");
scanf("%d",& n);
int a = n-2000
if (a<0)
{
printf ("Eres analogico");    
a= a*(-1);
}
else 
{
printf("Eres digital");
a = a*1;
}
int edad = a+(output-2000)
printf("Tu edad es:" + edad);
return (0);
}
```